# Retrieving and displaying logged in info in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to retrieve my logged in user data to no avail. Please check my

```
enter code here private function getUserData($user_name)
{
    // if database connection opened
    if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
        // database query, getting all the info of the selected user
        $query_user = $this->db_connection->prepare("SELECT * FROM users WHERE user_name='$_SESSION['user_name']'");
        $query_user->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_user->execute();
        // get result row (as an object)
        return $query_user->fetchObject();
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

Comment: You bind a value to `:user_name` which isn't in your SQL statement.

Comment: You've missed the entire point of prepared statements, which is to replace the injected variable with a placeholder, and move the variable to the bind method. In your version, you've got the variable in both places. Study the examples at https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#prepared closely.

Comment: @NigelRen :user_name is in my sql statement ,,

Comment: , @ADyson could you please code an example of how i should put it

Comment: what you've done now (following your last edit) should be sufficient to return the row data. What specific issue are you having now? "to no avail" is not a useful technical description of your problem. Please tell us specifically what happens when you run the code - e.g. do you get errors, or is the result not what you expected?

Comment: @ADyson in my loggedin.php  after running this script it only echos two variables The user_name and the gravar image the rest bring about an error to unidentified varriables yet i fetched them           
echo WORDING_YOU_ARE_LOGGED_IN_AS . $_SESSION['user_name'] . "<br />";
echo WORDING_YOU_ARE_LOGGED_IN_AS . $_SESSION['phone'] . "<br />"
echo WORDING_YOU_ARE_LOGGED_IN_AS . $_SESSION['firstname'] . "<br />"
echo WORDING_YOU_ARE_LOGGED_IN_AS . $_SESSION['lastname'] . "<br />"
echo WORDING_YOU_ARE_LOGGED_IN_AS . $_SESSION['service'] . "<br />"
?>

Comment: That has nothing to do with the code you've shown, or at least not directly. Per your code, you're getting those variables from the Session, not from the database. I have no evidence to show how (or even if) you saved that data from database to session first.

Comment: I get you @ADyson .thats the code am asking for  how i should code it to display my logged in user info after the user_name and user_ id is already set in session ..hope you get me..

Comment: You'd have to do something with the result of getUserData(). But since we know nothing else about your app, about the context in which you're calling this function, or using this data, it's impossible to give a precise answer. I guess you need to assign (or maybe re-assign) something into the Session variables. But it's completely unclear. You'd need to edit your question to give a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of the problem

Answer (score 0):

Got the way to move about it ,Thanks @ADyson for the response and follow up
code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>

  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <title>YOUR ORDER , We will contact you in a few !!!!</title>

  <link href="assets/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="assets/css/main.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!--[if lt IE 9]>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.2/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
      <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
    <![endif]-->
    
</head>
<body>

  <?php include 'header.php'; ?>

  <section>

    <div class="container">
      <strong class="title">MY ORDERS</strong>
    </div>
    
    
    <div class="profile-box box-left">





 <?php


 
  require('db.php');

  // SQL query

  $strSQL = "SELECT user_name, phone, firstname, lastname, service, referal,user_registration_datetime FROM users WHERE user_name = '".$_SESSION['user_name']."'";

  // Execute the query (the recordset $rs contains the result)
  $rs = mysqli_query($myConnection, $strSQL);

  // Loop the recordset $rs
  // Each row will be made into an array ($row) using mysqli_fetch_array
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($rs)) {
echo  WORDING_PROFILE_PICTURE . '<br/>' . $login->user_gravatar_image_tag;
   

         echo "<div class='info'> <strong>NAME:</strong> <span>".$row['firstname'].", ".$row['lastname']."</span></div>";
          echo "<div class='info'><strong>phone No:</strong> <span>".$row['phone']."</span></div>";
          echo "<div class='info'><strong>SERVICE:</strong> <span>".$row['service']."</span></div>";
          echo "<div class='info'><strong>REFERAL:</strong> <span>".$row['referal']."</span></div>";
          echo "<div class='info'><strong>DATE QUERIED:</strong> <span>".$row['user_registration_datetime']."</span></div>";
          

  }

  // Close the database connection
  mysqli_close($myConnection);

  ?>



       

      
      <div class="options">
        <a class="btn btn-primary" href="editprofile.php">Edit Profile</a>
        <a class="btn btn-success" href="changepassword.php">Change Password</a>
      </div>

      
    </div>

  </section>


    <script src="assets/js/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="assets/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="assets/js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: This should be done properly using prepared statements. Also please learn how to use stackoverflow's formatting tools - https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting - so that you can show your code in a clear way

Comment: What has this got to do with CodeIgniter? It's vanilla PHP.

Comment: @ADyson thanks am still learning how to move around here ,am very new

Comment: That's fine, that's why I gave you the link, so you could improve your posts :-)